# How to create a table with non-unique id and have it as foreign key in another table?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have the following tables in models.py:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    partno = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    partdesc = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, blank=True, null=True)

class Price(models.Model):
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datestart = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('supplier', 'part'),)
```

This is properly working. The problem is I have many part numbers which are their replacements. For example part 1001-01, 1001-02, 1001-03 are all the same part. Still, I have all of them in my Part table.

I need to match them in another table, so I don't need to enter price for each of them separately. There must be a unique key representing all of these three items.

**Question:** How do I setup a "part number match table" and have a foreign key to this table in my Price table?

***(Rest is optional to read which are my opinions/problems so far, might help though)***

**1:** I tried to setup the table like this:

```
class PartMatch(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=False, null=False, db_index=True)
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I don't get an error while migrating but when I try to use the same id for PK, it doesn't allow me.

**2:** I left the pk alone and tried to setup another field to match parts:

```
class PartMatch(models.Model):
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    partmatchid = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=False, db_index=True)
```

I don't get any error while migrating but when I try to use `partmatchid` as a foreign key in my `Price` table like this:

```
partmatch = models.ForeignKey(PartMatch, to_field="partmatchid",
                                  db_column="partmatchid",
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I get an error saying `foreign key must be unique` while migrating.

**Well in this case I am out of solutions. I wonder how you guys handle this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Part` model can have a foreign key to `PartMatch`, not the other way around.

Your model can be `Part *<-->1 PartMatch` and `PartMatch 1<-->1 Price`

For example:

```
class Price(models.Model):
     price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)


class PartMatch(models.Model):
    price = models.OneToOneField(Price, primary_key=True)


class Part(models.Model):
     partno = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
     partMatch = models.ForeignKey(PartMatch)
```

If you want to get all parts with some price, `some_price.partmatch.part_set.all()` will do the job.

Comment: Got it, gonna try that. Thanks

Comment: Ok I did what you have suggested, but now I can only display the price of only one part from PartMatch table. How can I display all three part numbers' prices going through `Price -> Part where Part.Partmatchid = Partmatch.id`?

Comment: I followed the path `Price -> Part -> Partmatch` and chose to enter price for each part individually since I couldn't find a way to do what I want. I accept your answer because it helped me. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry not to reply earlier. Great I could help you. What you wanted was to get all part with some price? Check the edited answer to be more descriptive.